# Make square buttons in TableLayout

Tags: android

I am using the following code to generate a table with button in each cell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the function that generates the table

```
 private void BuildTable(int rows, int cols) {

  // outer for loop
  for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

   TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
   row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

   // inner for loop
   for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {

    Button bt = new Button(this);
    LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
    bt.setLayoutParams(lp);
    bt.setText("R"+i+" ,C"+j);
    row.addView(bt);

   }

   table_layout.addView(row);

  }
 }
```

Which gives me the following:

[image]

I need your help to make the height of each button the same as its width. (As squares)

Thanks

Comment: You should create a Custom View that extends `Button`. Override the `onMeasure()` method, and apply the same height as the width.